# How to get MAX Hike in Min month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

below is table:

```
Name |  Hike%  |  Month
------------------------
A         7         1 
A         6         2
A         8         3
b         4         1
b         7         2
b         7         3
```

Result should be:

```
Name |  Hike%  |  Month
------------------------
A         8         3
b         7         2
```

Comment: its Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
 Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home Single Language 10.0 <X64> (Build 17134: )

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
SELECT Name, [Hike%], Month
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Hike%] DESC, Month) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Name;
```

If you instead want to return multiple records per name, in the case where two or more records might be tied for having the greatest hike%, then replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK`.

Comment: does mysql support [] bracket in name ?

Comment: @fa06, late info says OP is using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

use correlated subquery

```
select   Name,min(Hike) as Hike,min(Month) as Month  
from
(
   select * from tablename a
        where Hike in (select max(Hike) from tablename b where a.name=b.name)
)A group by Name
```

Comment: I just edited the table, if there is same Hile% in 2 months then we should get min month as the expected above.

Comment: I did like this:   with t as
(  select * from HIKEData a
where hikePer in (select max(hikePer) from HIKEData b where a.name=b.name))

select Name, min(Month), max(hikePer) hikePer  from t group by Name

Comment: @SubodhAgrawal, here max(hikePer) or min(hikePer) will do the same becuase it will have only one value :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to the below:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Hike), Month
FROM table
GROUP BY Name, Month
```

Hope this helps :)